# Why won't my VSCode terminal change style?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: Current terminal look]

After reinstalling VSCode my terminal has lost all its colour configurations and refuses to change. Changing themes does nothing. Editing the JSON file with custom colours does nothing. I'm not entirely sure how this has happened.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

Just uninstalled and reinstalled. Unsure of the cause.